# How to improve font loading/caching with Vercel/Next.js?

Tags: caching, fonts, next.js, webfonts, vercel

I use custom fonts on a website. It works, but it looks like they aren't cached long enough, as I way too often get FOUT. Some times multiple times a day, on production. I'm hoping I can cache fonts for a longer period (or another solution) to prevent this from occurring as often.

Fonts are preloaded in `_document.tsx` like this:

```html
<link
   rel='preload'
  as='font'
  href='/fonts/Calibre-Regular.woff2'
  type='font/woff2'
  crossOrigin='anonymous'
  />
```

Then in `_app.tsx` like this:

```js
<script jsx>{`
 @font-face {
  font-family: 'Calibre';
  font-display: swap;
  src: url('/fonts/Calibre-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('/fonts/Calibre-Regular.woff') format('woff');
}
`}</script>
```

**How can I improve this? Or set a longer cache time for the fonts?**

Comment: I am running into this, it seems, as my fonts are re-downloading after first interaction of site.. so, it downloads multiple times.. which causes shift. Do you have gist of what you ended up doing?

Comment: I ended up importing `@font-face` in an external `fonts.css` file, which I import `import "lib/fonts.css"` in `_app.tsx`. You can also prefetch the fonts using `<link rel="preload" href"...`. I didn't do the last part, but this setup works great. Seems like everything is cached better when it's an external css file, than directly in `_app.tsx`.

Comment: I put the "@font-face" in my global.css file BUT I do put my "<link etc.." IN the _document file. Should those go into _app instead?

Comment: Yes, they should go in `_app` and you can import them globally by doing: `import "lib/main.css";` on the top of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the full example, I’d:

- confirm first that your React app is server rendered. With Next.js, I’d imagine it is, but the `link` tag and `script` (which should be a `style` tag?) should be part of the initial HTML
- check if changing the inline CSS into a `<link />` tag and separate CSS style that, which only contains the `@font-face` declarations. Yes, this adds one additional HTTP request, but then that CSS would presumably follow Vercel’s static caching rules and not change for 31 days: https://vercel.com/docs/edge-network/caching#static-files (although it’s unclear here whether the cache is invalidated when you redeploy that file, or when you do any deploy)
- decide to use something custom to override Vercel’s default cache settings, and add a [Routes property in your vercel.json file](https://vercel.com/docs/configuration#routes/headers).

For example, to cache everything in the `fonts/` directory for one week (and assuming the new, external CSS file is there as well), the config would be:

```js
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/fonts/(.*)",
      "headers": { "cache-control": "s-maxage=604800" },
      "dest": "/fonts/$1"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is based on the config example in the docs: https://vercel.com/docs/configuration#routes/headers

Hope one or more of those together is helpful!

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I haven't had time to fully test this yet, but I'm pretty sure I will be able to solve my issue with these tips. Gave you the bounty before it expires, but will get back to you with the results. :)

Comment: Looks like it's much better now. :) I moved the `@font-face` to en external `.css` file, and imported that as a global css file (not scoped), in `_app.tsx` like this: `import lib/main.css`. That seems to be cached properly. :)

Comment: The updated vercel docs URL: https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/edge-network/headers

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be so sure that FOUTs are caused by the fonts not being cached long enough. Could they be *not yet loaded*, for example? The `preload` link should cause the browser to request the font and cache it normally - the WOFF(2) files are static files anyway. Unless special pains are taken to *not* cache them, they should be cached *and* stay cached.

So, I would *first of all* check the request **and response** headers for those WOFF files, both from the client and the server. What is it exactly that gets sent *to* the Vercel layer? And, more important, *what is it that gets sent from the server to the cache?* (I have misplaced enough cache-related pragmas myself that I now always check those first).

If that is OK, and I wouldn't bet on that, I would look at the actual load times and request waterfall from the site during a FOUT. This might point to caching problems or errors in the load sequence (much more rarely, but I have my share of those too).

If nothing shows out at this point, you could try to get rid of FOUTs otherwise - load animations, load delay, or just [hiding the text](https://css-tricks.com/fout-foit-foft/).

But my money is on the server-Vercel leg of the journey, 70% on the server sending borked headers, 30% on Vercel not reacting properly.

A dirty and terrible way to be sure whether it is the cache or something else is to have another machine prod the cache continuously at appropriate intervals from the same network (e.g. a cron job, or even more brutal, a `while` loop with `curl` and `sleep` from a terminal on a commodity Raspberry), at a frequence higher than that of the FOUT occurrences. If that makes the FOUTs disappear, then it might really be the caching time -- but frankly, I'd be really surprised.